# Error con album vacio, no se cual puede ser mi error

Tags: python

¿Me pueden ayudar con este error?

Tengo que tener este resultado esperado:

`{"nombre": "Mimos son Mimos", "artista": "Babasonicos", "album": "Trinchera"}`

pero al resolver solo me sale:

`{"nombre": "Mimos son Mimos", "artista": "Babasonicos", "album": []}`

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me aparezca el nombre del álbum?
este es mi código:

```
def obtenerAlbum(self):
        albumes=[]   
        albumes_todos=biblioteca.Biblioteca.obtenerAlbumes()
        for album in albumes_todos:
            for canciones in album.obtenerCanciones():
                if self.id == canciones.obtenerArtista().obtenerId():
                    albumes.append(canciones)
        return albumes
```

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el problema.

Comment: Una posibilidad es que `[]` venga en los datos de entrada. ¿Revisaste eso?